# Giving a custom name for a column in dataframe, Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

Defining a custom name joining certain previously defined strings like so:

```
df[:join([Str1,Str2,"_",Str3])] = zeros(length(df[:Str1]))
```

Returns the following error:

```
MethodError: objects of type Symbol are not callable
```

I understand that `join` doesn't work like that. Is it possible to convert `join([Str1,Str2,"_",Str3])` to a variable?

Comment: df[Symbol(join([Str1,Str2,"_",Str3]))] seems to be one of the ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings with the star * operator

```
field_name = "Str1" * "Str2" *"_"* "Str3"
```

or you can do it with string function

```
field_name = string("Str1","Str2","_","Str3")
```

Comment: That is one more way of achieving what `join([Str1,Str2,"_",Str3])` is doing, thanks! I found one way to use custom column names by doing so: df[Symbol(join([Str1,Str2,"_",Str3]))]

Answer (score 0):

```
df[Symbol(join([Str1,Str2,"_",Str3]))]
```

Does the job.